# "Reverse" case-control: is there a way to match most DISsimilar "controls" to my cases?

Tags: matching

For one of my analyses, I have to find cases that are most different from my cases. It's like case-control matching, but "controls" should be as different as possible. What would be a good method to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what you hope to accomplish by this deliberate and extreme mis-matching. There might be something reasonable to try to do what you suggest. Perhaps there's a better way to accomplish what you ultimately want with a different approach that might be easier to explain to a skeptical audience. Please provide additional information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.